# How can I render a component which has been imported with "require"?

Tags: react-native

file ToRender.js:

```
...

const ToRender = props => (
    <View />
);
export default ToRender;
```

another file:

```
let ToRender = require('./ToRender');
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {ToRender} // got Invariant Violation error
            </View>
        );
    }
);
```

I know that I can do it with "import"

```
import ToRender from './ToRender';
// then use it in the render method <ToRender />
```

But I'm wondering whether it's possible to do this with a "require"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export default class myView extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
   <View/>
   )
  }
}
```

Then Import it and use it:

```
import myView from "./myView.js";

<myView>
```

This should work. Require is not supported in React-Native anymore. It was replaced with "Import". Hope this helps!

Comment: As i sad I know that I can do it with import. Is "require" not supported?
I still see it in official documentaion. For example the Image component use it to load source:
<Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')}/>

Comment: @Obi1 Yeah sorry i didn't see that bit. Its supported but you cannot dynamically load components with it. "Import" is async and it dynamically loads your components. This is the main difference i know of. Why do you want to use require? Import would work fine for you as you already know.

Comment: I develop a component with similar API to react Image, so i need to pass a require(“some/path”) as prop as Image do, but unlike Image my component has only javascript implementation.

Comment: @Obi1 maybe try changing const ToRender = props => (
    <View />
);
export default ToRender; to use a class like my example above? And then use Require.js in the other file? That might work. Not sure though.